# deb package with architecture-specific dependencies

Tags: ubuntu, deb

I need to create a package, that has an additional dependency on Intel architecture.
A working RPM package.spec file goes like this:

```
Requires:       bc
%ifarch x86_64
Requires:       msr-tools
%endif
```

But I seemingly fail to define similar logic in DEBIAN control file:

```
Depends: bc, msr-tools:amd64
```

is greeted on ARM with

```
application-x : Depends: msr-tools:amd64 but it is not installable
```

but I don't want it on ARM.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships) gives an example for defining architecture-specific dependencies:

> ```
> Depends: foo [i386], bar [amd64]
> ```
>
> becomes `Depends: foo` when the package is built on the `i386` architecture, `Depends: bar` when the package is built on the `amd64` architecture, and omitted entirely in binary packages built on all other architectures.

In your case, that would be `Depends: bc, msr-tools [amd64]`.

Comment: Thanks !  I have seen this link, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, at least on Ubuntu 18.04 ('Depends' field, syntax error after reference to package 'msr-tools').

Comment: You may want to share more about how you are creating and building the package. Are you using the dh sequencer?

Comment: No, I actually don't use dh. I create (with some helper script magic) a package directory tree (DEBIAN and Linux root directory overlay), and run "dpkg-deb --build $(DEB_TOPDIR) $(DEB_OUTFILE)" - fairly simple. AFAIU dpkg-deb is the one reading the control file.